# Making Items In Your Hot Bar In Minecraft Turn To A Stack Of 64 When The Items Are Enchanted

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In a video I watched at 6:52, PopularMMOS turned 6 pieces of clay into a stack of 64 with the 6 pieces left. How does he do that?

Answer (score 2):

Middle clicking on the item ([or whatever button you have assigned to pick block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnjlL.png)) in creative mode will create a stack of the highlighted item.